# Find the four elements of $M(S)=\{\pi, \rho, \sigma, \theta\}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Question from Marcel Finan's *A Semester Course in Basic Abstract Algebra*.

Consider the set $S=\{a,b\}$. Find the four elements of $$M(S)=\{\pi,\rho,\sigma,\theta\},$$
where $M(S)$ is the set of mappings from $S$ to $S$.

I'm just confused. So these mappings are from S to S but S only has 2 elements.

Comment: What is M(S) ? ${}$

Comment: Any mapping from $S$ to $S$ has to send $a$ to either $a$ or $b$ and $b$ to $a$ or $b$. So we have $2 \cdot 2 = 4$ options which correspond to the four different mappings

Comment: Why the downvotes?  Lord Bellington, that is what I thought, but it seemed that $\pi(a)=a, \rho(a)=b$ aren't mappings in the sense that they send any element in S to an element in S, they send specific elements.  In other words, there is no $\pi(b)$

Comment: M(S) is the set of mappings from S to S

Comment: A mapping $\pi : S \rightarrow S$ has to send every element in $S$ to some other element in $S$. So the mapping $\pi$ that you gave is not a mapping, since $\pi(b)$ is undefined. We need to define $\pi(b)$ to be either $a$ or $b$ in order for $\pi$ to be a mapping from $S \rightarrow S$.

Comment: Okay, that was my confusion.  In this particular case, since the cardinality of S is less than the cardinality of M(S), we have to explicitly define each mapping.  I thought that was the case before I asked but I wanted to be sure.

Comment: @YACP, I wrote them as sets but they aren't appearing as such.

Comment: I think the problem statement is confusing. Simply saying "the four elements of $M(S)$" would have been enough and less confusing than giving them names that are not necessarily uniquely assigned. Additionally, just because oen writes $S=\{a,b\}$, it doesn't mean that $S$ has two elements. To have that, one should have $a\ne b$. It seems that this important premise has been left out from the problem statement.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen, the problem was written as it was in the book.  I like what you have to say about the problem though, it makes it clearer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given $\;S = \{a, b\},$

Each mapping $m: S \to S$ (where $m \in M(S)$) must send $a$ to either $a$ or $b$ and must send $b$ to $a$ or to $b$:

So we have $2⋅2=4$ mappings which correspond to the *four different mappings*

$$M(S)=\{\pi,\rho,\sigma,\theta\},$$ where $M(S)$ is the set of mappings from $S = \{a, b\}$ to $S = \{a, b\}$.

So we can arbitrarily assign each of the four distinct mappings a distinct "name":

$$ (\pi): \quad a \to a,\; b\to a \\ (\rho): \quad a\to a,\; b\to b \\
(\sigma): \quad a\to b,\; b\to a \\  (\theta): \quad a\to b,\; b\to b $$

Comment: clean write up +1

Comment: Well, it's rather $|B|^{|A|}$.

Comment: @amWhy: Sleep tight. :-)

Answer (score 4):

The four mappings are:
$$1.)\quad\quad a\mapsto a,\ b\mapsto a \\
2.)\quad\quad a\mapsto a,\ b\mapsto b\\
3.)\quad\quad a\mapsto b,\ b\mapsto a \\
4.)\quad\quad a\mapsto b,\ b\mapsto b
$$
I don't know how they wanted to distribute these among the given greek letters..:)